# Composer spoils configuration

Tags: php, composer-php

I use alternative composer_local.json configuration to configure local repositories and packages.

After running `COMPOSER=composer_local.json composer update` composer adds `php` to the root configuration.

e.g.:

before:

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.4",
    ...
  }
}
```

after:

```
{
  "php": {
    "version": "7.4"
  },
  "require": {
    "php": "^7.4",
    ...
  }
}
```

Composer still can understand modified configuration, but linter won't pass it.

Somebody knows why this modification happens and how I can prevent such behavior?

Comment: Isn't this more about trying to see if you can get linter to pass the new version rather than removing it from composer?

Comment: No, I wouldn't want to change linter settings. I want to understand why composer spoils the config and how can I stop him.

Comment: What have you tried to check where this comes from - for example, which version of Composer do you use? Does this happen in all constellations, or is there maybe any plugin that changes the configuration? I've never seen such configuration in any of my projects